# JQuery Selectors: How do I select the submit button of the second form on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

How do I select the submit button of the second form on a webpage?

Am I able to able to submit said form by using the .click() function on the selected submit element?

This is the script I am using in attempt to do so currently:

```
function Ellipsis_Mouse_Click()
{
     $("form:eq(1):submit:eq(0)").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: You should add IDs to make it easy!

Comment: I would just give the form an ID (or an ID on the submit button) and then use jQuery to control the action. You could also use the form ID to control the submit $('#formID').submit(function(){ // process submission }); Just don't forget to preven default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To select the second form:

```
$('form').eq(1);
// Or
$('form:eq(1)');
```

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) works from a zero-based index, hence using `.eq(1)` instead of `.eq(2)`.

This isn't a particularly good way of selecting the form as it's vulnerable to any DOM changes (whether made manually or with more JS). Consider adding a class or ID to the form, or select it relative to a container that has a class or ID.

To submit the form:

```
$('form').eq(1).submit();
```

You don't need to find the submit button and trigger a `click` on that. Instead, you can just call `.submit()` on the form itself.